# Listen to all events under a jQuery namespace?

Tags: jquery, events, namespaces

Is it possible to listen to all the events from a particular jQuery namespace?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
$element.on ( '.namespace', handler );
```

And `handler` should get called when `anything.namespace` gets triggered.

Is it possible?